# What's the correct UML notation for instantiating one object inside a method of another object?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uml

I'm working in Objective-C/CocoaTouch and want to notate the instantiation of a UITabBarController object by my AppDelegate object (inside the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method).

The app delegate object isn't storing the UITabBarController as an ivar; it's simply allocating and initializing this object. The object will be used for the life of the app, as the root view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `<<instantiate>>` dependency relation starting at the `AppDelegate` and ending at the `UITabBarController`. See the example provided [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html?cid=26)